# Someone with opposing personality traits

Tags: single-word-requests, oxymoron, personality

I'm looking for a word for someone with personality traits that oppose each other. Not someone two-faced but more like someone who is two sides of a coin but a the same time; like shy but outgoing, dominant but submissive, selfish but generous, or vain but hates them self. A walking-talking oxymoron but that's not the word I'm looking for either. It was used by a teacher to describe me but I cannot remember it.

Its either *adj* or *n* but I cant quite remember the context; something like:

> You have a very *insert word* personality, or
>   Your conflicting personality makes you a *insert word*.

Comment: A *paradox*, or is that too generic?

Comment: @Lawrence Or _paradoxical_, since the questioner seems to be looking for an adjective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for “not having a definite form”? - a person with opposing personalities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539747/word-for-not-having-a-definite-form)

Answer (score 1):

You might say that the person is ***complex***, or ***complicated***.

This  characterization is often used in situations where a person exhibits contradictory tendencies.

Urban Dictionary even has an entry for *complicated*:

> When your emotions are constantly in conflict with each other, and you just want to escape the world.
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=complicated)

That said, these words are also used to describe a person who has a deep or nuanced personality, so they may be a bit more general than what you're after.

>

Answer (score 0):

### Conflicted

Your second example 'Your conflicting personality makes you a...' provides the clue; *conflicted* works as an adjective.

From the [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conflict):

> *as adjective* conflicted: 
>   Having or showing confused and mutually inconsistent feelings.
>   ‘he remains a little conflicted about Marlene’

So as in your first example:

> You have a very *conflicted* personality.

Answer (score 0):

is it enigmatic, by any chance?

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference to your chosen word and an explanation as to why you chose it.

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-faceted or duality might be a better way to describe them without sounding judgemental. I'm looking for a more suitable word too.

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference to your chosen words and an explanation as to why you think they fit this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The word **dichotomy** means something with seemingly contradictory qualities.

So, the usage could be *You have a dichotomous personality*

Also, I would suggest not using 'very'. Any word that needs very before it, can be replaced by a more sophisticated word.

Answer (score 0):

What about contradicting or opposing

Per M-W:
[contradicting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contradicting)

> implying, causing, or being a contradiction
>
> CONTRADICTORY
>
> *contradicting statements   
>
>
> The detectives found contradicting evidence.*

[oppose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposing)

> 1: to place over against something so as to provide resistance, counterbalance, or contrast
>
> *one military force opposed to another 
>
>
>  concreteness as opposed to abstraction
> —L. E. Lynch* 
>
>  2: to place opposite or against something 
>  
> *oppose the enemy*

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference to your chosen words and an explanation as to why you think they fit this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe self-contradictory?

EDIT - My initial answer was the following, but I realise that this is incorrect:

> Dare I say schizophrenic fits the bill - i.e. split personality? I think this not exactly what you are looking for, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Just FYI, *schizophrenic* does not mean "split personality", though the Greek etymology would suggest it does. No, the word simply means "unable to determine what is real". The term for split personality is the disappointingly straightforward "multiple personality disorder".

Comment: Shows I should have checked first. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as a comment at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Were you looking for *diametrically opposing*?

Comment: This could be a good answer if it had more content - like an explanation, an example, even a citation. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).