# Word for “not having a definite form”?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for something with a constantly changing or not easily identifiable form?

Example: If a person sometimes acts shy but other times is more extroverted, so you’re not sure how to describe their personality — is there a word for that state of not really knowing what category a person or thing falls into?

Answer (score 2):

*Temperamental* is what you're looking for.

A **[temperamental](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/temperamental)** person is someone whose behaviour is unpredictable or whose mood changes suddenly.

**[Capricious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capricious)** and [**mercurial**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mercurial) can also be used for such kind of person.

> **Mercurial:** If you describe someone as mercurial, you mean that they frequently change their mind or mood without warning.
> [[Collins Dictionary]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/mercurial)

> **Capricious:** having a tendency to sudden unpredictable changes of attitude or behaviour. [[Collins Dictionary]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/capricious)

*Due to their capricious and [erratic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/erratic) behaviour, they are unclassifiable.*

---

> If a person sometimes acts shy but other times is more extroverted

**[Ambivert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambivert):** a person whose personality has features typical of both introverts and extroverts.

Comment: Yes to all above (except perhaps "ambivert" for its oddness), but "mercurial" is the one that popped into my mind first.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

[Ephemeral](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ephemeral?s=t) Lasting a very short time; short-lived; transitory.

[Volatile](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/volatile?s=t) Changeable; mercurial; flighty; fleeting; transient.

[Elusive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elusive?s=t) Eluding or failing to allow for or accommodate a clear perception or complete mental grasp; hard to express or define.

Answer (score 0):

[*'Enigmatic'*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enigma) could be the word you are looking for.

Comment: You should include the dictionary definition of the chosen word that makes it suitable in this case.

Comment: I think the choice is obvious for any native speaker. However,  as for your curiosity, see sense 2 at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enigma

Comment: If you edit that link and that definition into the answer, it will be a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[**Inchoate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inchoate) may serve.

Strictly speaking it means imperfectly formed or not fully formed, but your audience may not quibble about that subtle difference.

Answer (score -1):

The term **chameleon-like** (sometimes, see eg Merriam-Webster, without the hyphen, *chameleonlike*) is used of such people. [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chameleon-like) defines the metaphorical usage of the noun:

> *chameleon* [noun]  ...
>
> - (2) a changeable or fickle person
>
> adjective: *chameleon-like*