# Word for simultaneously same and different

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an adjective that means simultaneously same and different?

Sample sentence:

> The brothers were [WORD]: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers.

Searches I’ve done:

- same
- Congruent
- Different
- similar
- Dissimilar

If there are no such adjectives, are there any compound words that could serve instead? Ideally something that isn’t too long, but really stresses the superposition of similar and different.

This request is not like [Word for “not having a definite form”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539747/word-for-not-having-a-definite-form) as the forms are known and unchanging. The form of the brothers is a highly-overlapping venn diagram: the intersecting section is the known, unchanging "same", and the indepedent sections are the "different" or "dissimilar". The key part of this sought-after word is that it identifies that what it describes have two known and unchanging opposite sets of traits (opposite on an arbitrary axis).

Comment: **Ambivalent**.

Comment: You could say that the brothers are [**chameleonic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/chameleon). This fits the quotation better than the question title.

Comment: It's not quite the same question, but **enigmatic** might work well here.

Comment: There is no such word. None of the suggestions in the comments above, or the answers below, mean anything close to what you want.

Comment: You can consider *mirror image*, with some literary license.

Comment: I agree with @TonyK, none of these answers satisfy the original ask. Most of the words describe the state of having different characteristics (ambivalent, chameleonic, multifaceted).

The closest is superposition, but it lacks the specification of which states are in superposition.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat

Comment: If there were an adjectival verison of Schrödinger's cat, that would be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on context. While I don't believe there is a perfect single word for this, this is certainly a common and generally recognized concept. Most famously, *A Tale of Two Cities:*

> ```
> It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, 
> it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, 
> it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, 
> it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, 
> it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, 
> we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, 
> we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way
> ```

The above quote is describing the same thing as a multitude of contradictory (to the point of being exact opposite) statements. The author of the book put the thing in **juxtaposition** with itself. Usually, one would **juxtapose** two (or more) different things beside each other to compare/contrast them, but in this case the author is doing a **self-juxtaposition**.

If your context is the same as the quote, one could describe the thing as being **in a state of superposition,** referring to a state of [Quantum Superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) wherein a thing is both states of a binary relationship (both alive and dead) at the same time.

In math, namely geometry, to describe things that are almost the same but not exact, you would say they are **similar but not congruent** (a 5in. x 5in. square is similar to a 6in. x 6in. square, but not congruent).

A common proverb you could use to describe them could be **different sides of the same coin**, meaning that both parties are the same thing, just from a different angle.

And I feel that an **oxymoron** comes close to matching with your description, but doesn't quite get there.

Since there unfortunately isn't a perfect single word for this phenomena I would think the best way to go about describing it would be to explain it in a few words:

"The brothers were **arbitrarily either on the same or different side of the same coin**: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers."

"The **brother's personalities were in a state of superposition**: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers."

Personally, as a phrase, I like "same, yet opposite."

"The brother's were **the same, yet opposite**: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers."

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted as I think it comes closest to answering my original ask:


- there is no such word
- the closest one-word approximation is "superposition"
- the best phrase is "the same, yet opposite"
- the perfect imaginary word would be a union of superposition and oxymoron.

thank you!

Comment: I just came across [vicissitude](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vicissitude). Specifically, the literary meaning seems to come pretty close to what I asked for, with the exception of "being simultaneous"

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the title of the question, this is asking about having multiple qualities *at the same time*, not necessarily about something that ***actually*** changes from one thing to another over time. (Although it might appear so to an observer.)

A word to describe something like this is [**multifaceted**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multifaceted):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : having many facets (see FACET sense 1) or aspects
> // a *multifaceted* approach to health care
>
> *facet*
> **1** : any of the definable aspects that make up a subject (as of contemplation) or an object (as of consideration)
>     // Each *facet* of the problem requires careful attention.

It could be used in the example sentence in the following way:

> The brothers were *multifaceted*: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers.

However, it would be more natural to put the emphasis on something like their personalities in this context:

> The brothers had *multifaceted* personalities: sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers.

Using this word, it doesn't mean that their personalities as a whole change, but that a particular aspect will be more apparent than another at any given time.

Answer (score -1):

How about **semi-similar** or **semisimilar**? From M-W:

> **[semi-](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semi-)**: to some extent : partly : incompletely

> **[similar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/similar)**: having characteristics in common

**Semi-similar** (or **semisimilar**) implies simultaneous similarity and dissimilarity. Your example:

> The brothers were [*only*] **semi-similar** (or **semisimilar**): sometimes they seemed like the same person, at other times they didn’t even seem like brothers.